# React wait until set state in the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having problems with a react function,
When my main function is finishing another one is triggered.
So I depend on this function NOT end until the state is updated.
What I can do?

```
 _toggleIsCollapsed = () => {
    const { isBlocked } = this.state;
    if (isBlocked) {
      console.log('blocked');
    }
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ isCollapsed: !prevState.isCollapsed }),
      () => {
        console.log('isCollapsed: ' + this.state.isCollapsed);
        console.log('done1');
      }
    );
    // Always this line is fired first
    console.log('done2');
  };
```

The result I want to achieve is this:

```
// done1 
// done2
```

Comment: move everything you want to execute after state update to the callback?

Comment: Yes-setState doesn't immediately set the state, it queues up the state change.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a function after `setState` finishes and invoke the second param in `callback` like:

============Pseudo code =========

```
this.setState({
    title1: 'updated title 1'
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.title2, 'titl2')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected because setState is asynchronous.

From your question, I don't see any reason why you can't just do:

```
_toggleIsCollapsed = () => {
    const { isBlocked } = this.state;
    if (isBlocked) {
      console.log('blocked');
    }
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ isCollapsed: !prevState.isCollapsed }),
      () => {
        console.log('isCollapsed: ' + this.state.isCollapsed);
        console.log('done1');
        console.log('done2'); // move this here
      }
    );
  };
```

If you want the function to do other stuffs only after the state is updated (done1 is logged), you can just do this:

```
handleAfterStateChanged = () => {
     // do more stuff here
     // this will only be called after the state is updated
 }

 _toggleIsCollapsed = () => {
        const { isBlocked } = this.state;
        if (isBlocked) {
          console.log('blocked');
        }
        this.setState(
          prevState => ({ isCollapsed: !prevState.isCollapsed }),
          () => {
            console.log('isCollapsed: ' + this.state.isCollapsed);
            console.log('done1');
            this.handleAfterStateChanged();
          }
        );
      };
```

Answer (score -1):

you can put a setTimeout() on the part of the code that depends on the state that is changing in setState

I am using you want done1 to come before done2

```
_toggleIsCollapsed = () => {
    const { isBlocked } = this.state;
    if (isBlocked) {
      console.log('blocked');
    }
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ isCollapsed: !prevState.isCollapsed }),
      () => {
        console.log('isCollapsed: ' + this.state.isCollapsed);
        console.log('done1');
      }
    );
    // Always this line is fired first
    setTimeout(() => console.log('done2'), 200)
  };
```

Comment: @DaveNewton I would love to know a better solution.. I am not being sarcastic but it will help me in my codebase

Comment: If you have stuff that must execute before the next render, and relies on a state to be updated at an arbitrary time in the future, then it belongs in the callback function. A timeout will either fire too early or too late.